# Understanding and Fixing User Permissions Logic in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I know this might be a silly question but please don't laugh at me.  I am struggling to understand this simple logic. I am not understating why this logic is not working where it means if request.user is not the owner of the object or the user is not an admin user. The first part of this logic works to prevent other users from overwriting the owner object but why second part not working where a user can be overwritten object if he is an admin user?

```
if (request.user != comment.user) or (not request.user.is_superuser):
```

why my above logic only working for if user != owner of the obj ? why admin user can't edit if he is an admin?

but this logic works on both part

```
if not (request.user.is_superuser or (request.user ==  blog.blog_author)):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two statements act differently because they *are* different. You can use De Morgan's laws to prove this.

When distributing a negation across an `and` or `or`, you need to change the `or` to an `and`, and vice versa.

Stated more formally, [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) say that

- not (A or B) = (not A) and (not B)
- not (A and B) = (not A) or (not B)

Let's apply De Morgan's laws to the second example you give, to make it look more like the first example, without changing its meaning.

```
if not (request.user.is_superuser or (request.user ==  blog.blog_author)):
# Apply De Morgan
if (not request.user.is_superuser) and (not request.user == blog.blog_author):
# Combine not and equals into not equals
if (not request.user.is_superuser) and (request.user != blog.blog_author):
# Re-order terms
if (request.user != blog.blog_author) and (not request.user.is_superuser):
```

You can see that this is different from your first example:

```
if (request.user != comment.user) or (not request.user.is_superuser):
```

Without more context, I can't say whether an `and` or an `or` is correct here, but that's why the two statements act differently.

Comment: thanks for your explanation.  The main concept is I want only the object owner or a super user can edit. it's not mandatory the object owner will be a super user either he can be a super user or object owner. so what will be the correct logic here?

Comment: That depends on what is after the if. The question doesn't say whether the code after this if is the branch where the user is allowed to edit or the branch where the user is denied the right to edit. The thing about De Morgan's law is all I can say without knowing that.

Answer (score 2):

This condition does not work because the way its processing.
In case of OR operator, system check the first condition, if its true then, it doesn't check the second condition.

So in your case suppose superadmin is logged in and try to edit other user object

condition 1: request.user != comment.user // become true, and it never check second condition for superadmin user.

you should swap the condition with AND, I think that will work.

Code:

```
if (not request.user.is_superuser) and (request.user != comment.user):
     #do whatever you want
```

Comment: yes ur condition working but how it's working? and I know both should be true for `AND` but your logic working Where one is true and another is false

Comment: I am assuming, this condition you wrote to redirect user, who is not allowed to edit object. So It first check user is not a superuser, if True then check user shouldn't be object owner, if both conditions satisfy, redirect the user. If you can share full code, that would be helpful to better understand the issue.